# How can I use a for loop to append from a Pandas DataFrame column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas DataFrame that contains a Column of Integers. I'm trying to use a for loop to pull out only the Count values of that DataFrame where the 'Artist' column matches 'The Beatles'.

```
tot=[]

for art in df:

    for df['Artist'] in art:

        if art['Artist'] == 'The Beatles':

            tot.append(artist['Count'])

The Dataframe format is as such:


'''

Rank    Album   Artist  Count
1   1   The Beatles [White Album]   The Beatles 1634
2   2   Rubber Soul The Beatles 1497
3   3   Revolver    The Beatles 1489
4   4   Abbey Road  The Beatles 1468
5   5   Meet Me in St. Louis    Judy Garland with Georgie Stoll and His Orchestra   1399

'''

I receive the "TypeError: string indices must be integers".
```

Comment: I want to be able to show the Total of 'The Beatles' counts in comparison to the total and the visualize it afterwards.

Comment: Can you provide the df.head()?

Comment: Sounds like a job for `df['column'].value_counts()`, `df.query()`, `df.groupby()`, `df.filter()`, or any of the other methods for selecting data from a dataframe. Looping is almost never the best option in pandas.

Comment: What is your expected output from this small dataset?

Comment: I wanted to create a list containing the count sum of 'The Beatles' albums from a table of 100 albums, and then compare that count to the total (using a Pie Chart eventually). This was the code I needed: 'df.loc[df['Artist'] == 'The Beatles', 'Count'].sum()'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to save a array with all `Counts` where Artist is The Beatles, use:

```
df.loc[df['Artist'] == 'The Beatles', 'Count'].tolist()
```

if you need to sum all the Counts, use `.sum()`

```
df.loc[df['Artist'] == 'The Beatles', 'Count'].sum()
```

Answer (score 1):

### Method 1:

If you want to count the entry `The Beatles` in your `Artist` column from your DataFrame, you don't have to do a loop.

Use `pandas.DataFrame.groupby` instead, with `.transform('count')`. It will give you the count of each entry of your `Artist` column.

```
df['Count'] = df.groupby('Artist')['Artist'].transform('count')
```

Which gives:

```
>>> data = ['The Beatles', 'Some Artist', 'Some Artist', 'The Beatles','The Beatles','The Beatles']
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns = ['Artist'])
>>> df
        Artist
0  The Beatles
1  Some Artist
2  Some Artist
3  The Beatles
4  The Beatles
5  The Beatles
>>> df['Count'] = df.groupby('Artist')['Artist'].transform('count')
>>> df
        Artist  Count
0  The Beatles      4
1  Some Artist      2
2  Some Artist      2
3  The Beatles      4
4  The Beatles      4
5  The Beatles      4
```

This is helpful if you want to graph your result. Just create a dictionary with `keys` equal to `Artist` column value and `values` equal to `Count` column value.

The repition won't be a problem since python dictionaries does not allow duplicated values on `keys`. Doing so:

```
>>> artist_count_dict = dict(zip(df['Artist'],df['Count']))
>>> artist_count_dict
{'The Beatles': 4, 'Some Artist': 2}
```

You may now access those values for your graphing purposes.

### Method 2:

You can also use `df['Column Name'].value_counts()` to give you the stats you need.

```
>>> df['Artist'].value_counts()
The Beatles    4
Some Artist    2
Name: Artist, dtype: int64
```

Create a new dataframe if you need to store it into one:

```
>>> df2 = df['Artist'].value_counts()
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2)
>>> df2.index.name = 'Artist'
>>> df2.columns = ['Count']
>>> df2
             Count
Artist
The Beatles      4
Some Artist      2
```

Answer (score 0):

I pressume you are looking for this

```
tot = df.loc[df['Artist']=='The Beatles','Count'].tolist()
```